# Not all subcategories are displayed into permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have some nested categories, like those

```
Ospitality 
  Where to sleep
    Italy
    Germany
    Uk
  Where to eat
    Italy
    Germany
```

All posts belonging to Where to sleep have a good permalink, showing all categories and sub categories

https://sitename/ospitality/where-to-sleep/italy/postname

But, all posts belonging to Where to eat does not show the third level category

https://sitename/ospitality/where-to-eat/another-postname

Is there a good reason for that?

Comment: Did you try regenerating the permalinks?

Comment: Yes, of course.
The problem is that the same content types have different behaviours with different categories